# Как подключить стили в django, и можно ли использовать их вместе с бутстрапом?

Tags: css, django

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
```

настройки django
приложение выглядит примерно так:

```
project/
app1/
    templates/
        base.html
app2/
mainapp/
static/
    css/
        styles.css
```

project/
app1/
templates/
base.html
app2/
mainapp/
static/
css/
styles.css
Не совсем понимаю, как подключить в последней версии джанго в base.html, который находится в app1

Comment: <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> Так не работает?

Comment: `<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> `

Comment: <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
пишет неизвестный тег static

Comment: <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> добавил в css файл стиль body с background: blue; но ничего не поменялось

Answer (score 0):

папка `static` обычно используется для хранения окончательной версии всех статических файлов твоего проекта, которые собирается из всех приложений, которые в нем участвуют + общих для всех статических файлов. Изначально хранить общие статические файлы в ней на мой взгляд плохая идея, так как после выполнения команды `collectstatic` файлы в ней могут быть перезаписаны и если запутаться с именами, можно перезаписать один файл другим без возможности восстановления нужной версии(без исопльзования сторонних инструментов).

Поэтому я бы выделил две папки
`static/` - в которую будут собираться все статические файлы со всех приложений проекта и `staticfiles/` - папка в которой хранятся статические файлы общие для проекта, не зависящие от конкретного приложения.
Внутри `staticfiles` можно настроить нужную тебе структуру папок, например:

```
staticfiles/css
staticfiles/js
```

и в настройках проекта `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

...

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')  # папка в которую будут собираться статические файлы
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'staticfiles'),  # папка из которой будут собираться общие файлы для всех проектов
]
```

Перенеси `css/styles.css` в папку `staticfiles`
дальше в шаблон `base.html` как тебе указали можешь добавить строчку

```
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Так же нужно учитывать, что обычно работа со статикой не входит в обязанности django, это работа веб сервера, но на момент разработки, что бы не усложнять себе жизнь, можно заставить джанго обрабатывать статику. Сделать это можно изменив файл urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

...

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```